# setup a using if the current object is null

Tags: .net, entity-framework, using

I'm trying to make this code be a little less duplicated, I feel like there should be a way of initialising a using statement if the object is already null

```
public static CMSContent GetContent(string title, ContextDb db = null)
    {
        if (db == null)
        {
            using (db = new ContextDb())
            {
                return db.CMSContents.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Title == title && !c.Archived);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return db.CMSContents.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Title == title && !c.Archived);
        }

    }
```

The reason for this is because the calling statement might want to run further db requests on the returned object, or there might be several calls and the connection is setup ahead of time to mitigate multiple connections.

What would be better is if the return statement could not be duplicated, so if db is null then using then do.

Comment: This appears to me to be a matter of design confusion. While the method is simple, which is good, there seems to be a bit of confusion as to what is the responsibility of the method. Is it meant to retrieve data or create the context? Giving a method too many responsibilities cause the kind of problem experienced above.

Comment: It's not the way I prefer to program, but it's an old project and I'm in a team, and I can't go rewriting it.

Comment: Then you are in a bind. the using statement is scope based so there is no way that if you create the the db within that method that its scope extends beyond that method and there also no way to tell if the provided db, when not null is within a using scope.

Comment: That's the conclusion I'd come to, I was hoping someone would prove me wrong. :(

Comment: There is no escaping technical debt. It calls in the loan eventually. looks like you got stuck with the bill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement), you can achieve the same behavior by calling `Dispose()` in a `finally` clause.

**Edit**: regarding the comment of Nkosi - we would have to remember if `db` was null initially. Not sure if the resulting code is really an improvement, at least the return statement is not duplicated anymore...

```
public static CMSContent GetContent(string title, ContextDb db = null) {
    var dbWasNull = (db == null);
    try {
        if (dbWasNull) {
            db = new ContextDb();
        }
        return db.CMSContents.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Title == title && !c.Archived);
    }
    finally {
        if (dbWasNull) {
            db.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that if the OP wanted to access the db outside of this method it would cause an error as the db would have already been disposed.

Comment: Ah good point, this is only the same behavior if `db == null` is true :( I edited my code to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I took Georg's answer, as edited, and trimmed it up a bit:

```
public static CMSContent GetContent(string title, ContextDb db = null)
    {
        var _db = db ?? new ContextDb();

        try
        {
            return _db.CMSContents.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Title == title && !c.Archived);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (db == null) _db.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I did a lot of hunting round for a better answer and I can't find one. Except perhaps don't do this and have a connection pool managed by a singleton. But that's not practical here and hopefully this will serve to help someone else.

I did come across the idea of not disposing the context and letting GC do that, but I don't think I could sleep at night if I did.

```
public static CMSContent GetContent(string title, ContextDb db = null)
{
    return (db ?? new ContextDb()).CMSContents.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Title == title && !c.Archived);
}
```

Yeah - don't do that. Apparently EF5 would have been OK with that, something about it closing the connection automatically, but EF6 isn't and if it's disposable you should be disposing it.